# Link badge to a list of my posts matching badge's requirments

Tags: feature-request, badges

Please link the badges page on my page to a list of posts that are eligible for that badge, instead of the people who have it.

For example link the [`Great Answer`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer) badge, to the [`Great Answers`](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/q/4777/undefined?UserId=16487) query.

[image: Image of badges]

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve some of these results using various advanced search parameters:

[Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+views:1000)
[Notable Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+views:2500)
[Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+views:10000)

[Nice Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+views:1+votes:10)
[Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+views:1+votes:25)
[Great Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+views:1+votes:100)

[Enlightened](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+isaccepted:1+votes:10) (This may not be correct if your answer wasn't the first answer)

[Scholar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:1+views:1)
[Student](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+votes:1+views:1)

Comment: Good use of the search options.

Answer (score 4):

**List  of badges and queries**

If this suggestion is implemented, this might make it easier. If not, it should provide an inferior alternative. This post is CW, so feel free to add other queries.

**Gold**

- Great Question -> [Great Questions](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/224/great-questions)
- Great Answer -> [Great Answers](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/219/great-answers)

**Silver**

- Favourite Question -> [Favourite Questions](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/222/favourite-questions)
- Good Question -> [Good Questions](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/225/good-questions)
- Good Answer -> [Good Answers](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/227/good-answers)

**Bronze**

- Nice Question -> [Nice Questions](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/220/nice-questions)
- Nice Answer -> [Nice Answers](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/221/nice-answers)

Comment: The queries will use old data which may not be useful.

Comment: @KennyTM - it's only a month old at the greatest.